# std::optional::value_or() - lazy argument evaluation

Tags: c++, stl, c++17, stdoptional

Is it possible to evaluate `std::optional::value_or(expr)` argument in a lazy way, so the `expr` were calculated only in the case of having no value?

If not, what would be a proper replacement?

Answer (score 28):

```
#include <optional>

template <typename F>
struct Lazy
{
    F f;  

    operator decltype(f())() const
    {
        return f();
    }
};

template <typename F>
Lazy(F f) -> Lazy<F>;

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> o;

    int i = o.value_or(Lazy{[]{return 0;}});
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68660776247975dc)

Comment: What kind of construct is `template <typename F>
Lazy(F f) -> Lazy<F>;`  ?  It looks like a forward declaration of a function template with trailing return type, but it isn't...

Comment: @BenVoigt it's a template deduction guide

Comment: `operator decltype(auto)() const` is nicer IMO (less parens). :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 oh god this breaks my brain... "Hey here's a conversion for... um... well we'll see!"

Comment: @Rakete1111 There's also `operator invoke_result_t<F>()`

Answer (score 12):

You may write your helper function:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
T lazy_value_or(const std::optional<T> &opt, F fn) {
    if(opt) return opt.value();
    return fn();
}
```

which can then be used as:

```
T t = lazy_value_or(opt, [] { return expensive_computation();});
```

If that's significantly less typing than doing it explicitly that's up to you to judge; still, you can make it shorter with a macro:

```
#define LAZY_VALUE_OR(opt, expr) \
    lazy_value_or((opt), [&] { return (expr);})
```

to be used as

```
T t = LAZY_VALUE_OR(opt, expensive_calculation());
```

This is closest to what I think you want, but may be frowned upon as it hides a bit too much stuff.

Comment: "you can ease this up with some macros" - please don't advocate the use of macros.

Comment: @JesperJuhl just like `goto`, macros are a tool and have their place, even in modern C++; demonizing them tout court, as for any "absolute" judgment, is wrong and shortsighted. This case is a bit borderline, as it hides quite some stuff (and I even warned about this), but that's up to OP to judge.

Comment: They are a tool in the toolbox, sure. And they have their uses. But, I don't think we should go around advocating their use since *most* use of macros is bad or inappropriate - *most* things can be done better without the use of macros. So yes, they exist. They serve a purpose. Just don't mention them unless they are the last and *only* resort (IMHO).

Comment: As a naming note, some languages (e.g. Rust) call this `value_or_else`.

Answer (score 1):

C++23 adds a closely related feature: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/or_else

```cc
std::optional<int> f();
std::optional<int> g();

std::optional<int> y = f().or_else(g);
```

Note however that the `or_else()` argument itself returns `std::optional<T>` rather than `T`.

So 3 options, all a little bit clunkier than envisioned:

- In C++23, use `f().or_else(g).value()` if available and `std::optional<T>` return type for the `or_else` argument isn't a bother.
- Use a helper function template like `lazy_value_or(f(), g)`, sacrificing the monadic method chain syntax.
- Write out `auto opt = f(); return opt? std::move(*opt) : g();`

Answer (score 0):

Make an optional of function type.

Then a lambda can be passed in, which when called will calculate the correct value at the requested moment.

```
std::optional<std::function<int()>> opt;

int a = 42;
opt = [=] { return a; }

int b = 4;

int c = opt.value_or([=] { return b * 10 + 2;}) ();
```